# FlickrAPI metadata

Tags: flickr

How do I get the image metadata details such as person uploaded, spatial coordinates,and tags assosciated with the image.I have seen the FlickAPI documentation but I couldn't find any suitable method.

I can use flickrAPI.photos.getRecent() but it doesn't give me the image details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [flickr.photos.getInfo()](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) has all the information that you are looking for.